# how to integrate countdown and alarm in xcode iphone? please provide source code

Tags: iphone

how to integrate countdown and alarm in xcode iphone?  please provide source code.....
i have tried a lot...but didn't find any specific solution...please help me...

Comment: Hi Mohit, have a look at http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to see how to ask a question that's easy to answer.

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried and maybe someone can show you where you went wrong? Asking people to write code for you is a little beyond what this site is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A countdown would not be very hard to integrate, just use an NSTimer:

```
NSTimer *countdown = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerTicked:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Simply countdown the timer for as many seconds as you want:

```
- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer *)countdown{
    seconds--; // Some pre-declared variable

    // UI Updates Here if you want

    if (seconds <= 0)
        [countdown invalidate]; 
}
```

---

An alarm would be a little more complicated, but still not too hard. There's a few ways you could do it depending how you are setting the alarm. If it's soon just use a timer:

```
NSTimer *alarm = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:SECONDS target:self selector:@selector(alarmDoneMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

However I'm assuming for an alarm you want it to be able to be set hours or days in the future. In this case use an NSDate.

```
NSDateComponents *alarmComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init]; 
[alarmComponents setMinute:userInputMinute];
[alarmComponents setHour:userInputHour]; 
[alarmComponents setDay:userInputDay];
[alarmComponents setMonth:userInputMonth];
[alarmComponents setYear:userInputYear];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *alarm = [gregorian dateFromComponents:alarmComponents];
[alarmComponents release];
```

Now just set a timer (I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this but I can't think of it off the top of my head at the moment, it's still early in the day) to check if your alarm has been reached:

```
NSTimer *checkAlarm = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkAlarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; // Checks every minute
```

Then inside the checkAlarm: method just see if the alarm has been reached:

```
-(void)checkAlarm:(NSTimer *)t{
    if ([[NSDate date] earlierDate:alarm] == alarm){
        // Alarm reached
        [t invalidate]; 
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Great answer. The only issue is that NSTimer is not millisecond accurate. It works off of run loop cycles instead of real time. That could cause some bugs. That said, I'm not aware of any alternative other than `wait()` :p

Comment: Ya it's true, but it's the simplest solution I can think of and it should work accurately enough. It's not very often you need alarms or countdowns to be millisecond accurate anyway.